# Serenity BDD: What is the best approach to go with while doing automation with serenity BDD? Junit or Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd

I want to implement Serenity BDD for my project.
There are 3 ways to do it.
Cucumber, junit or Jbehave.

Which will be the best one to go with?
Some of my tests are data-driven.(up to 40-50 records).If I need to implement that with cucumber
then I need to pass data from examples (Scenario outline). I think It's incovenient to pass all data from feature file.

I am doing it currently with junit.
just thought whether it could more better with Cucumber or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best approach, I guess you've already known that. Below are some points to help you choose the better in your context.

- **Development process - BDD or not BDD**:

If your team goes with truely BDD, that means you have feature, user story, examples to demonstrate system functions, then you definitely should go with cucumber:

1. You've already have examples (don't need to re-write)
2. BA, Dev, Tester and other stakeholder understand your tests when seeing the serenity report.

> Ok, now that you know that BDD is about discovery, collaboration and
> examples (and not testing), let’s take a look at Cucumber.

[Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/overview/)

But if other members (PM, customer) only care the number of the tests, pass or fail, then go with JUnit. You don't need to write and maintain the human-friendly feature files to make test run. You can achieve the same thing by `@Step` and `@Steps` in JUnit.

- **Technical aspect**:

Both approachs are able to do data-driven test easily,

1. `scenarios outline` in Cucumber will map to [`List` or `Map`](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#step-arguments).
2. JUnit 5 convert `@Source` to [any object](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) you want. It seems JUnit is more dynamic.